# How should I save user access code securely in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, password-encryption

I'm trying to create an application that'll allow the user to use an access code emailed to them to gain access to their account. How should I store this access code and use it to check which user is trying to gain access?

The user doesn't have to provide their email, so there's no easy way for me to check if the hashed access code in the database without going through each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [has_secure_token](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SecureToken/ClassMethods.html). Just store it in a database (let's say, as `access_token` attribute) and when user is trying to access, find user by access token that is provided as a parameter.

```
User.find_by(access_token: params[:access_token])
```